# how the value changes dynamically

Tags: java

I have compiled the following code,

```
import java.lang.*;
public class Test
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int x=010;
    System.out.println("x(010):="+x);

}
}
```

After compiling the code, i got the value 8 but the actual value of x is 10, how it happens to print the value 8, could you please someone explain me the reason.

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1 - the compiler is doing exactly what it's meant to...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It starts with a 0, so it's in octal notation.

Actually, the value of `x` is `1*8^1 + 0*8^0 = 8`.

As the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1) states:

> An octal numeral consists of an ASCII digit 0 followed by one or more
>   of the ASCII digits 0 through 7

```
OctalNumeral:
    0 OctalDigits
```

Answer (score 1):

`int x = 010` the prefix "0" in the value of `x` made the compiler treat it as an octal value.

Answer (score 1):

In java if you start with 0 then you are telling that the number is in octal.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1

> An octal numeral consists of an ASCII digit 0 followed by one or more of the ASCII digits 0 through 7 interspersed with underscores, and can represent a positive, zero, or negative integer.